# How to restrict taxonomy term reference with certain terms?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

In a node edit/add form, I need to show a field with dropdown/select list options (Cardinality unlimited). I do not want all the taxonomy terms of that vocabulary to appear. I want to show certain terms. The vocabulary has 2 level hierarchy. First dropdown in the form element shows only parent terms. On selecting parent term from the dropdown, certain child elements should show in the second dropdown.

Comment: i think there is no module for such feature, you should do it in custom code, by implementing `hook_form_alter` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`

Comment: 1) Hook form alter is not working for altering options for widget.  Hook form alter does not work because these options are again rebuild after the form is altered. 2) hook_field_widget_form_alter is not  altering the options.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking 2 questions here:

- Restricting Terms: You can edit the entity reference field's **Reference method** to use a new custom view that filters only the criteria you're looking for.
- Parent/Child Widget: The [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) did have this widget functionality in D7, in D8 there are a few modules out there, like [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) & [Client-side hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs), that have similar dual-selection functionality.

Comment: These both "Restricting Terms" and "Parent/Child Widget:" do not work simutaneously. Simple hierarchical select and Client side hierarchical select  are not working when I am using with views entity reference. Either restricting term functionality work OR the parent child.

Answer (score -1):

Check for the D8 module [Tac Lite](https://www.drupal.org/project/tac_lite)

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please add information on how this module solves the original question. Please also refer to the [Help Center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to see what answers are acceptable on this site.